# How to remove this warning to this php script

Tags: php

I have this php query, which join many table from (baby class up to standard seven), so that I may get the Total SUM form SUM of each table.

But when I run the query it gives me Warning says

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects   
parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in   
C:\wamp\www\db_valentine_V2\Templates\school_income.php on line 872
```

Am trying to sort out in line 872 where there is this script

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
```

Can any one help me to remove this warning, Its real takes me long time without any success.

```
  <?php

 $date="date";
 $class="class";
 $database=("mcl");
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","mcl");
 @mysql_select_db(mcl) or die( "Unable to select database");


if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
$class=$_POST['class'];
$date=$_POST['date'];


$sql="SELECT SUM(Total) FROM 
    ( SELECT     
   SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+food_fee+
  uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total FROM payment UNION  

    SELECT SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+
   food_fee+uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total FROM payment_one UNION
  SELECT    SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+food_fee
  +uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total   
        FROM payment_two UNION
   SELECT   SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+food_fee
  +uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total   
        FROM payment_three UNION
  SELECT   
 SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+food_fee+
 uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total   
        FROM payment_four UNION
  SELECT SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+food_fee+
  uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total   
        FROM payment_five UNION
 SELECT   SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+food_fee+
 uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total   
        FROM payment_six UNION
 SELECT SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+food_fee+
 uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total   
        FROM payment_seven )a)";


 $q=mysql_query($sql);  

    }

  ?>


<form method="post">
<table width="500" border="0">
 <tr>
<td>Class</td>
<td><input type="text" name="class" value="<?php echo $class;?>" /></td>

<td>Year</td>
<td><input type="number" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>" /></td>

<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br />
   </form>
    <table>
    <h4>
   This is total amount of money payed by&nbsp;<?php echo $class;?> &nbspclass     
   in&nbsp<?php echo $date;?>&nbsp;</h4><hr> 
   <table width="700" border="0" height="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
   <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF9900" width="50">Class</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FF9900" width="300">Total amount of money payed</td>

   </tr>
  <?php
   while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){

       ?>

     <tr>
     <td width="100"><?php echo $res['class'];?></td>
     <td width="200"><?php echo $res['SUM(Total)'];?></td>

     </tr>

    <?php }?>    



     </table>
```

Comment: fix your query because it fail.

Comment: use $q=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Can you show what `$q` is?

Comment: You should also switch your mysql queries to mysqli

Comment: Please also consider looking into using `PDO` instead, particularly prepared statements, which can help guard against SQL injection. The `mysql_*` family of functions are deprecated as of v5.5: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
while(!empty($q) and $res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
```

Comment: You probably mean while(!empty($q) && $res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){

Comment: Yes, It works very much, thank u Mariyo

Comment: J2D8T: why do think **&&** is better than **and** in this solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your code variable `$q` has not the scope to access outside the if condition.

So you need to define it before your if condition. Add the below line above the if condition.

```
$q="";
```

And in place of the while loop use this:

```
if(!empty($q)) {
   while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
           -----------
          your code
          ---------------
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
if($q === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }

while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    //do here
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to post the codes, but now is okay